# Hibernate @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) implementation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When persisting to the database, does hibernate use the `name` implementation of the enum or the `toString`? I'm reading conflicting things online, just wanted to clarify. I am using hibernate for Postgres. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, @Enumerated uses ORDINAL.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html

Using this
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) will store Enum's name() (not toString()).

Comment: Correct. You can see this by looking at the code in `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.EnumJavaType` in Hibernate 6.